# ant.properties to get alias & password parameters from file

Tags: android, ant

I'm trying to add my alias and password to ant.properties file.
I was wondering if there is a way to store them in an unrelated file, and tell ant.properties to read those values from this file.

These are the params that I want to save on a different file (in order to avoid committing it to git.

```
key.store.alias = my_alias
key.store.password = my_password
key.alias = my_alias
key.alias.password = my_password
```

Your help is much appreciated,

Thanks,
Giora.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you mean build property file for ant build?
If yes, why do you need to include the file in build property file?

If you are using a CI server like Jenkins, you can write a small shell/command script using `echo` or `printf` commands to append required properties to build properties before the build.

E.g. `echo -e "\nkey.store.alias = my_alias\nkey.store.password = my_password\nkey.alias = my_alias\nkey.alias.password = my_password">>$WORKSPACE\build.properties`

You can even use these variables as build parameters if its dynamic and you don't wan't to hardcode the values esp the password.

Comment: Thanks a lot for answering. I did use the dynamic way eventually. using the -Dkey=value option.